# editable rich text for WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, richtextbox, itemtemplate

(using VS 2010)

I have a `Combobox` with `IsEditable` set to `True` (ie, the user can select items from the dropdown, but also edit the text of the selected item). Additionally, I want certain keywords to be automatically bolded and possibly colored. In other words, the text will not have uniform styling. This is most important for the selected item, but it would be nice if the dropdown items also followed the same formatting convention.

`RichTextBox` seems to be the most recommended choice for implementing multiple text formatting, but I can't figure out how to properly implement it as my `ComboBox`'s `ItemTemplate`. This is what I have so far:

```
<ComboBox  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SearchText}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FileHistoryItems}">

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <RichTextBox Width="300" >
                    <RichTextBox.Document>
                    <FlowDocument >
                            <Paragraph>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox.Document>
                </RichTextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But this method is extremely clunky, with all kinds of selection/focus/editing issues. And I haven't even gotten to the code for formatting keywords yet.

Can anyone show me the proper way to use a `RichTextBow` for an editable combobox? Or any way to implement a `combobox` where the item text can have multiple formats?

Comment: Could you specify the goal you want to achieve with this combobox? I assume that the user can click it to choose from a given set of items or he could type in text that will be auto-completed. Is that correct?

I'm asking because I'm not quite sure if `RichTextBox` is the best control for this scenario.

Comment: @feO2x It should act like a typical editable combobox. The user can select items from dropdown, but also edit the selected item. The only difference is the formatting of the text. I will try to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot "restyle" the WPF `ComboBox` to use a `RichTextBox` by changing the control template - this is because the `ComboBox` expects an instance of a `TextBox` via the `TemplatePartAttribute` (you can have a look at the default style and control template of the combo box here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.100).aspx). `RichTextBox` does not derive from `TextBox` so you have no possibility to exchange it.

The next problem is that you cannot change the formatting of only some words within a regular `TextBox` - you can only change the formatting of the whole text but this is not the scenario you want. I just reflectored into the .NET code for `ComboBox` and `TextBox` and I would say there is no way to achieve that (as the important parts like the `TextContainter` class are internal).

So what are your options? You could implement your own `ComboBox` although this would take a lot of time and you should have a really thorough understanding of WPF - I would not advise this route.

Maybe the easiest way is to create a new control with the following control template structure:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:MyComboBox}">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True">
            <ComboBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <!-- Default Template for ComboBox but without the TextBox and corresponding visual state changes -->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ComboBox.Template>
        </ComboBox>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="TextHost" /> <!-- Make sure that this text box is properly aligned within ComboBox -->
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Your new control could derive from combo box and handle everything that is necessary to display the text of the current item as well as writing back the text when it is changed by the user - but this is also a lot of work and shouldn't be underestimated.

By this you would encapsulate the WPF combo box in a way. This solution might still take some days to implement but it should be faster than to build a combo box from start.

If you have any more questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I agree the best methods are probably too advanced (or too much work) for me. I will give this a try, or perhaps just formulate an ad hoc solution with a `richtextbox` and a `button` that triggers a `listview` popup. Not ideal of course.